# How to determine a very low frequency signal?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, dft

I have a noisy signal with frequency between 1/3 and 1/5 of the sampling window.

DFT has a very low resolution for low frequency components, what is the best way to find the frequence?

Comment: Do you mean you only get 1/3 to 1/5 of a period in the sampling window, or that you only get 3 to 5 periods in the sampling window?

Comment: I get 3-5 periods in the sampling window. I would like to find the frequency with a better precision then the FFT resolution.

Comment: @user175348: Have you tried interpolating the FFT output? https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Quadratic_Interpolation_Spectral_Peaks.html https://gist.github.com/endolith/255291#file_parabolic.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article by Eric Jacobsen and Peter Kootsookos:
http://www.ingelec.uns.edu.ar/pds2803/Materiales/Articulos/AnalisisFrecuencial/04205098.pdf

I had some success using this method for doing "sub-bin" frequency estimation when only one sinusoid is present.

Comment: +1 for Eric's work!  Check out his frequency estimation page here, too: http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe.htm

Comment: Updated paper link: https://www.academia.edu/download/70249550/04205098.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just zero-padding?

Suppose I have:

> SINE = sin(2*%pi*0.001923492369*[0:1023] + rand(1)*2*%pi);

[image]

And I zero-pad it:

> SINE_ZERO_PADDED = [SINE zeros(1,10240)];

Then I can take the FFT of both:

[image]

where the blue plot is the absolute value of the FFT of the original, and the red (dashed) plot is the absolute value of the FFT of the zero-padded signal.